# How do I cycle between 2 names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to cycle between 2 inputs/variables please help.
I would like it to switch between the names so it takes turns in asking the 2 players.
I am trying to code connect4, so it would take turns asking the player.
Sorry if this is a bit silly.
It is not returning both the names, just staying on one.

Thank you

```
from time import *

CurrentPlayer = 1
Player = " "
Win = False

def MainMenu():
    print("Welcome to Connect4")
    Name1 = input("Player 1, what's your name? ")
    print("Hello",Name1)
    while True:
        Player1Symbol = input("Do you want to be X or O? ").upper()
        if Player1Symbol == "X" or Player1Symbol == "O":
            print(Name1,"is" ,Player1Symbol)
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid option. Please choose X or O.")
            continue
    Name2 = input("Player 2, what is your name? ")
    while True:
        if Player1Symbol == "X" or Player1Symbol == "x":
            Player2Symbol = "O"
            break
        elif Player1Symbol == "O":
            Player2Symbol = "X"
            break
        else:
            print("ERROR unable to assign player symbols")
            break
    print(Name2,"is",Player2Symbol)
    print(" ")
    print("LOADING BOARD")
    print("-----------------------------")
    print(" ")
    sleep(2)
    return (Name1, Name2)

def Board():
    print(" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ")
    print("┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘")
    print(" ")
    
def returnCurrentPlayer(CurrentPlayer, x):
    if CurrentPlayer == 1:
        x = Name1
        CurrentPlayer = CurrentPlayer + 1
        return(x)
        return(CurrentPlayer)
    else:
        x = Name2
        CurrentPlayer = CurrentPlayer - 1
        return(x)
        return(CurrentPlayer)

def Turn():
    print(returnCurrentPlayer(CurrentPlayer, Player),"it's your turn")
    print("Please select column.")

Name1, Name2 = MainMenu()
Board()
Turn()
Turn()
```

[this is what ive done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKAfY.png)

Comment: you can only return from a function once. try changing your return lines to `return x, CurrentPlayer` as a first step

Comment: @vahndi Ive done this and it still only stays on the first name.

Comment: The `CurrentPlayer` in the `returnCurrentPlayer` function is not the same variable as the one defined outside the function, so changing the local one inside the function does not change the global one. If you want to change the global one you need to assign the result of the function to the global variable e.g. `CurrentPlayer, Player = returnCurrentPlayer(CurrentPlayer, Player)`. you should read a tutorial on Python scope if this is new to you.

Comment: Please ,please read about how to create a [mre]. According to your worded question there is really no need for this whole piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from time import *

CurrentPlayer = [1]
Player = " "
Win = False

def MainMenu():
    print("Welcome to Connect4")
    Name1 = input("Player 1, what's your name? ")
    print("Hello",Name1)
    while True:
        Player1Symbol = input("Do you want to be X or O? ").upper()
        if Player1Symbol == "X" or Player1Symbol == "O":
            print(Name1,"is" ,Player1Symbol)
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid option. Please choose X or O.")
            continue
    Name2 = input("Player 2, what is your name? ")
    while True:
        if Player1Symbol == "X" or Player1Symbol == "x":
            Player2Symbol = "O"
            break
        elif Player1Symbol == "O":
            Player2Symbol = "X"
            break
        else:
            print("ERROR unable to assign player symbols")
            break
    print(Name2,"is",Player2Symbol)
    print(" ")
    print("LOADING BOARD")
    print("-----------------------------")
    print(" ")
    sleep(2)
    return (Name1, Name2)

def Board():
    print(" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ")
    print("┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤")
    print("│-│-│-│-│-│-│-│")
    print("└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘")
    print(" ")
    
def returnCurrentPlayer(CurrentPlayer):
    if CurrentPlayer[0] == 1:
        x = Name1
        CurrentPlayer[0] = CurrentPlayer[0] + 1
        return x
    else:
        x = Name2
        CurrentPlayer[0] = CurrentPlayer[0] - 1
        return x

def Turn(CurrentPlayer):
    Player = returnCurrentPlayer(CurrentPlayer)
    print(Player,"it's your turn")
    print("Please select column.")

Name1, Name2 = MainMenu()
Board()
Turn(CurrentPlayer)
Turn(CurrentPlayer)
```

Basically what I have done is used a list for Current Player so that you can manipulate it and it remains changed overall.
I am assuming you are starting out with programming, and if you want to learn more you should read about references and scopes and functions and classes and how control is passed (basically which lines of code execute when)

You cannot have 2 return statements one below the other because the program will never reach the second return statement.